# Why does vscode remove the prefix from intellisense suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out why this is happening and how to stop it.

[image]

I'm typing `edi` in the screenshot and the autocomplete options are only the letters that come after `edi`. I'd like it to show the full name of the suggestions.

How can this be changed?

Comment: This is not standard behavior. What language are you in? Is this a VS Code `settings.json`?

Comment: This screenshot was in the settings.json yeah, but it also happens in typescript files and other files. I'm not sure what I could have done to trigger it. I only have tslint, prettier, and vim plugins installed on this laptop as well. Running on Ubuntu 18.04 but my other Ubuntu installs don't have this issue.